# Why do I get an SSL error when trying to download mini_magick

Tags: rubygems

I have ruby 1.9.3, WinXP Pro:

I'm new to ruby. I would be grateful for help in fixing the following error:

```
C:\>gem install mini_magick -v 3.5 --no-document
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mini_magick' (= 3.5), here is why:
   Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect retur
ned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (
http s://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the latest updates to RubyGems there have been some security improvements. one of those improvements is that it does not download gems from SSL sources when the SSL certificates are unknown. as rubygems does not come with a list of trusted sources by default, you have to add it manually.

an easy fix for that is to just use unsecure HTTP connections. you can use the sources command (`gem help sources`) to remove the https://rubygems.org/ url and use http://rubygems.org/ instead.